# How to find existed config linking for a solr collection?

Tags: solr

I have to manage an solrcloud with no delpoy docs for reference.

The solrcloud uses zookeeper for confs. I can see many conf sets but I don't know which are used for the collections.  Is there a way to find the linkconf config used?

Comment: can you elaborate little more about the issue? I mean how you uploaded the config to zk in first place?

Comment: my solrcloud has 4 collections, and in zk there is some configs. At first I don't know which config set is used. Now I have find the answer:  the solr admin menu cloud---tree on the left, and /collections/<colletionName> on the right, the configs used list on the bottom.